# Unbind [bindable]s

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

The tag [bindable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bindable) does not seem to have a well-defined purpose, and is littered over questions about different languages and toolkits.

Can someone guess a common meaning, create a tag wiki and clean up the questions that don't match, or shall we burn it down?

Comment: 40 questions.  Go ahead and knock it out.

Comment: @Will: Sure, but I don't know much about the topics of these questions, so I'd rather ask whether it is useful in some of those questions.

Comment: Smells meta.  I say burn it.

Comment: Looks like it has a tag wiki now. Not saying that it's a great tag wiki, but a starting point to explore the tag? (Just to check if it still warrants burnination).